# Expression "de toutes ses bielles"

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai trouvé plusieurs fois l'expression "**de toutes ses bielles**".

Par exemple : 1. "A quelques mètres des plages métamorphosées en barbecue gargantuesque, la route suisse vrombit **de toutes ses bielles**."

2. "... comme une locomotive folle lancée à toute vapeur, fumant **de toutes ses bielles** et de tous ses pistons..."
3. "La route commence à défiler comme je ne l'ai jamais vue, la moto vibre **de toutes ses bielles**, les suspensions tapent en butée..."

Est-elle un synonyme de "à pleine vapeur", "à toute vitesse" ? Cette expression **de toutes ses bielles** est-elle utilisée couramment ?

Answer (score 2):

On trouve cette rare expression dès 1930 :

> *La machine déchaînée, fumante **de toutes ses bielles**, acharnée à regagner un long retard, bondissant par-dessus le fleuve clair, crevant de sa masse vibrante, ivre de vent, les villes et les bois, les monts et le brouillard...*
> *La Revue universelle*, p 480, 1930.

Aussi chez Céline :

> *C'est pas terminé la musique, un autre archange nous assaisonne,
> fonçant du ciel **de toutes ses bielles**...* Céline, *Guignol's Band*, 1944

D'autres occurrences apparaissent épisodiquement depuis, sans qu'il y ait nécessairement de lien entre elles.

Elle est légèrement différente d'« **à toute vapeur** » car ici, ce n'est pas l'action du pilote qui « **met les gaz** » que l'on met en avant mais l'activité du moteur, la sollicitation de sa mécanique tout en mouvement. On est un peu plus proche du « **[toutes voiles dehors](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/mettre-toutes-voiles-dehors)** » d'un voilier ou d'une morsure ou d'un [sourire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sourire_de_toutes_ses_dents) faits « **de toutes ses dents** » qui ont peut-être inspiré l'expression.

Comment: L'avantage de la bielle est que c'est une pièce qui est présente à la fois sur les locomotives à vapeurs (et visible) et sur les moteurs à explosion (mais invisible).  L'expression laisse donc supposer que le moteur tourne à haut régime, mais pas forcément que le véhicule lui-même va vite.

Answer (score 1):

En comparaison avec « à  toute vapeur » ce n'est que très rarement utilisé.

[image]

Cependant, si c'est une expression qui peut correspond plus ou moins à un régime que l'on caractérise comme étant « à toute vapeur », elle ne saisit pas tout à fait cet état de « fonctionnement » selon le même aspectn :  au lieu d'une considération de l'effort produit selon l'aspect du grand niveau d'énergie déployée elle en  offre une  sous l'aspect de la demande extrême  qui est faite des « composantes » mises en action par cette énergie.
C'est pour cette raison qu'elle peut être employée, par example, pour un véhicule terrestre qui peine énormément dans une montée très raide et qui tout en n'étant  pas lancé à toute vapeur, donne des indication audible de pièces mécaniques mises à rude épreuve, des pièces telles que les bielles, typiquement.
Il faut remarquer que dans les phrases citées, le langage n'est pas très précis dans ses images se rapportant à cette pièce mécanique ainsi qu'à d'autres : un vrombissement n'est pas caractéristique du bruit d'une bielle (qui n'en fait pas à proprement parler, à moins d'être défectueuse) ; une bielle ne fume pas, ni un piston, et tout ce qui peut « fumer » dans une locomotive c'est essentiellement une soupape ; de plus il ne s'agit pas de fumée mais de vapeur.